# Array of characters in C without fixed size

Tags: c, arrays

How can an array of characters be entered without using a fixed length array in C?
I was given an assignment to center strings in C, and was told not to use a fixed size array.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to create an array without a fixed size is by using [`malloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d.aspx), which accepts the size (in bytes) of memory you want to allocate. You will then use it as a `char*`, which can also accomodate array syntax. **Do not forget** to test that the return value is nonzero (which is the way `malloc` indicates that you are out of memory).

After you are done using the memory, you are then responsible for releasing it back to the system with `free`.

For example:

```
size_t size = 42; // you can read this from user input or any other source
char* str = malloc(size);

if (str == 0) {
    printf( "Insufficient memory available\n" );
}
else {
    // Use the memory and then...
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: **No!** Don't cast the return value from `malloc`. In C, that is, at best, redundant and may hide an error the compiler would have caught without the cast.

Comment: @pmg Could you please give an example where compiler is hiding an actual error message. I tried to produce one but failed though.

Comment: @pmg: You are of course right, that's C++ habits at work. Edited to fix, thank you.

Comment: @MattJoiner: Are you referring to VLAs? Please keep in mind the level of the person asking the question, and the spirit of the assignment. Also, I would prefer to keep the discussion civil.

Comment: @Mahesh: failure to include `<stdlib.h>` leds compiler to assume `malloc` returns an `int`. See http://ideone.com/dQUo8

Comment: @pmg Thanks. I couldn't understand the second reasoning " if .... ". How could we relate that with current question. Could you please elaborate. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Mahesh: if pointers get passed on stack and ints get passed in registers, without a prototype in scope, the compiler will assume the value from `malloc` will be in registers ... but the function itself (from deep inside the library) put the value on the stack. [You can imagine what will happen](http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3W-29uAcctUOM_VENA5gUSQ-eK_CL_P7iFjjqYHxo7603oLe4noZ8Y5I) :)

Comment: @Mahesh: (continued) and with the cast the compiler will be silent. The absence of the cast wil make the compiler complain about assigning an int to a pointer.

Comment: For what it's worth, `malloc` returns `NULL` on error. Even though `NULL` is *usually* defined as `0`, it's not guaranteed to be the value `0` (in C).

Answer (score 3):

Look up the functionality of `malloc` and `realloc`.

I assume non-fixed size means dynamically allocated array - which can be obtained using `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do [dynamic memory allocation by `malloc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

[Example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/):

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    printf ("How long do you want the string? ");
    scanf ("%d", &i);

    char *buffer = malloc (i+1);
}
```

Comment: The cast is, at best, redundant and may hide an error the compiler would have caught withiut the cast.